# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2' HARD

Tags: python, windows, opencv, pycharm

This is the error Python gives me when I try to run the code. Does not find the cv2 plugin, although all dependencies are installed.

I tried Python 3.6 and 3.7, 32 and 64 bit versions. I tried to put through anaconda. But nothing helped.

```
import cv2

I try to run code to recognize objects, but I get errors: pydev debugger:
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.5\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1741, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.5\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1735, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.5\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1135, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/open_/PycharmProjects/firstAI/venv/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from imageai.Detection import ObjectDetection
  File "C:\Users\open_\firstAI\lib\site-packages\imageai\Detection\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

[image]

Comment: The Project Interpreter shown in the screenshot seems to have the opencv python module installed. Perhaps you could also check that your Run configuration uses the 'Project Default' interpreter (the interpreter can be overriden here). According to your screenshot, it seems the script was run with the virtual env of your project.